# Questions regarding chanting names

Tags: vedic-rituals

I am not initiated, and so I chant names of my Ishta Bhagavan/Mata (God/Goddess).

I have a few questions on chanting names:

1. Any general rules to be followed while chanting names?
2. Please guide on whether names require Purascharan for Siddhi?
3. If yes, are the rules for purascharan of names the same as that for mantras?

Please provide references where you can.

Thanks.